# Dozer, Java: How to convert from List<List> to 2D Array?

Tags: java, arrays, list, converters, dozer

I have a List of Lists which I'm trying to map to an 2 dimensional array [][] using Dozer and Custom Converter.

```
public class Field {
    List<String> items;

    public void add(String s) {
        items.add(s);
    }
}

public class ClassA {
    int anotherVariable;

    List<Field> fields;

    public void add(Field f) {
        fields.add(f);
    }
}

public class ClassB {
    int anotherVariable;

    String[][] itemValues;
}

@Test
public void convertListTo2DArray() {
    Field field1 = new Field();
    field1.add("m"); field1.add("n");

    Field field2 = new Field();
    field2.add("o"); field2.add("p");

    ClassA classA = new ClassA();
    classA.add(field1);  
    classA.add(field2);

    classA.setAnotherVariable(99);

    List<Converter> converters = new ArrayList<Converter>();
    converters.add(new ListToArrayConverter());

    ClassB classB = new DozerBeanMapper().setCustomConverters(converters).map(classA, ClassB.class);  

    /**
     * Result:
     * classB -> anotherVariable = 99
     *
     * classB -> itemValues[][] =
     * ["m", "n"]
     * ["o", "p"]
     */  
}
```

The Converter should only be used for converting between `List<List>` and `String[][]` and not for other variables.

I took a look at the answer in to the following question, but how should I handle Array instead of Set/List in that Custom Converter?
[Dozer Mapping from HashSet to Arraylist](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39676018/dozer-mapping-from-hashset-to-arraylist)

Any suggestions would be much appreciated.
Thanks

Comment: Is this code compile 'Class' start with capital class declare as 'Field' and call as 'Filed'

Comment: [@janith1024]: Thanks for the hint. I made the corrections you mentioned.

Comment: Hi @ThomasMuller , did the answer help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My java is a little rusty, bear with me.

If you want the converter to be used only for converting List to String array and not anything else, one of the ways you could restrict it is by specifying the custom converter for only those two fields in the xml:

```
<mapping>
<class-a>beans6.ClassA</class-a>
<class-b>beans6.ClassB</class-b>
<field custom-converter="converter.ConvertListToArray">
    <a>fields</a>
    <b>itemValues</b>
</field>
</mapping>
```

Next, the `items` attribute in your `Field` class and the `fields` attribute in your `ClassA` class needed to be initialized to arraylists to prevent them from throwing `NullPointerException`.

```
List<String> items = new ArrayList<String>();
List<Field> fields = new ArrayList<Field>();
```

Finally, here is the CustomConverter, assuming that the number of elements added to `fields` is always constant:

```
public class ConvertListToArray implements CustomConverter{
    public Object convert(Object existingDestinationFieldValue, Object sourceFieldValue, 
    Class<?> destinationClass, Class<?> sourceClass) {
        if(sourceFieldValue==null)
            return null;

        if(sourceFieldValue instanceof List && ((List<?>) sourceFieldValue).size()>0){
            List<Field> listOfFields = (List<Field>)sourceFieldValue;

            String[][] destinationValue = new String[2][2];
            for (int i = 0; i<2;i++){
                 Field f = listOfFields.get(i);
                 for (int j = 0;j<f.getItems().size();j++){
                     destinationValue[i][j] = f.getItems().get(j);
                 }
             }
             return destinationValue;

         }
        return null;
    }
}
```

Comment: Great job, thanks a lot for your help. Sorry for the unintentionally delayed answer.